# Problemas de trampolín en xcode 13.2

Tags: xcode, certificado-apple

tengo un problema con el simulador trampoline.Al ejecutar una app y abrirse el simulador se cuelga en attaching process, por que entiendo que no estaria conectando el codigo con el simulador y me tira un error del springboard.El otro dia mi mac se actualizo y xcode pidio para actualizar unos archivos, creo que desde ahi no funciono el simulador.

> Process:               SpringBoard [4350]
> Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
> Identifier:            SpringBoard
> Version:               1.0 (50)
> Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
> Parent Process:        launchd_sim [4333]
> Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [638]
> User ID:               502
> Date/Time:             2023-04-17 15:02:54.072 -0300
> OS Version:            macOS 11.7.6 (20G1231)
> Report Version:        12
> Anonymous UUID:        61BE7717-D983-3792-20C1-7EA38CFB8268
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       075C1150-56E7-4E02-8F3C-1BD42CEB0DE9
> Time Awake Since Boot: 5400 seconds
> Time Since Wake:       3500 seconds
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
> Crashed Thread:        0
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
> Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
> Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
> Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar código o trazas de error y demás detalles del contexto de la pregunta, no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. "Algo como" no es una descripción

Comment: okey, ahora anexo mas informacion, gracias